# Retrieve Child Derived Data Through Parent Base Data Pointer C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to design a hierarchy where derived classes containing a derived data type inherit from base classes containing a base data type, while exposing the functionality to retrieve children data polymorphically.

E.g. What I would like to do:

```
BaseClass* base = new BaseClass();
cout<< "base data: " << base->get_data()->my_base_str << '\n';

BaseClass* derived = new DerivedClass();
cout << "derived data: " << derived->get_data()->my_derived_int << '\n';
```

I have tried to return a pointer to the base data type and access the derived data members through said pointer, but of course the pointer isn't aware of the existence of the derived data members (nor should it be).

e.g.

```
class BaseDataType{
    public:
        BaseDataType() : my_base_str("base string"){}
        virtual ~BaseDataType() = default;
        std::string my_base_str;
};

class DerivedDataType : public BaseDataType{
    public:
        DerivedDataType() : my_derived_int(18){}
        int my_derived_int;
};

class BaseClass{
    public:
        virtual BaseDataType* get_data(){
            return &base_data;
        };
    private:
        BaseDataType base_data;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
    public:
    BaseDataType* get_data() override{
        return &derived_data;
    }
    private:
    DerivedDataType derived_data;
};
```

And of course I get the error:

> error: ‘class BaseDataType’ has no member named ‘my_derived_int’

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Your line `derived->get_data()->my_derived_int ` is something you are expecting to call only on the correct polymorphic version of the `BaseClass`, not on a general BaseClass. Then why not casting the pointer? If you want something more general, I suppose you should implement some polymorphism also on the data type. I do not know if I have grasped your issue actually, in case I am sorry

Comment: If your children classes can identify themselves, a block to choose the proper `dynamic_cast<>` could work. My suggestion would instead be to first attempt to implement a better interface that doesn't require this.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not recommend to do this, but if you have access to c++17, then you can have virtual function in `BaseDataType`, returning [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

```
class BaseDataType{
    public:
        BaseDataType() : my_base_str("base string"){}
        virtual ~BaseDataType() = default;
        virtual std::any get_data_any() const
        {
            return std::any(my_base_str);
        }
        std::string my_base_str;
};

class DerivedDataType : public BaseDataType{
    public:
        DerivedDataType() : my_derived_int(18){}
        virtual std::any get_data_any() const
        {
            return std::any(my_derived_int);
        }
        int my_derived_int;
};

class BaseClass{
    public:
        virtual BaseDataType* get_data(){
            return &base_data;
        };
    private:
        BaseDataType base_data;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass{
    public:
    BaseDataType* get_data() override{
        return &derived_data;
    }
    private:
    DerivedDataType derived_data;
};
```

If you don't have access c++17, there is also `boost::any`. And I feel the urge to state again that I really do not recommend this.

Here is demonstration of using the function.

```
BaseClass* base = new BaseClass();
std::string str = std::any_cast<std::string>(base->get_data()->get_data_any());

BaseClass* derived = new DerivedClass();
int i = std::any_cast<int>(derived->get_data()->get_data_any());

std::cout << str << i;
```

Comment: why do you not recommend it?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Because I believe OP has the opportunity to implement a better interface, which does not require my suggestion, just to keep the design simple and intuitive,

Comment: Besides OP may not have access to `c++17`, and be reluctant to add new dependencies to the project.